# Difference between "highestAvailable" and "requireAdministrator" in manifest in terms of Elevation?

Tags: windows, winapi, sdk, manifest

I used "highestAvailable" in my exe's manifest. But in `standard user and UAC ON` its not elevating the exe.

Is this the behavior of "highestAvailable"?

I referred this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) but its not clear whether "highestavailable" will elevate the exe or not. My requirement is to elevate the exe if UAC is on.

I changed to "requireAdministrator" and my exe is getting elevated in standard user with UAC ON.

Can someone explain me in detail about the elevation behavior of these two options "highestAvailabe" and "requireAdministrator"?

Comment: highestAvailable is just that, the highest available permission; the user is a standard user, so that's what is the highest. If you always need admin permissions, use requireAdministrator.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`highestAvailable` will elevate if the current user is an administrator. Which is consistent with what you have observed. When a standard user runs the process, no UAC dialog is shown and the process runs with the standard token. When an admin user executes, the UAC consent dialog is shown and the process will then run elevated.

If your program requires admin rights to function then you need to use `requireAdministrator`. When a standard user starts such a process, the *over-the-shoulder* UAC dialog is shown. That gives the user an opportunity to ask an admin to supply their credentials.

You should only use `highestAvailable` if your program is capable of running with a limited functionality in case the user is not able to elevate. This is what is meant by *mixed-mode* in the MSDN topic linked by your question.

Comment: An example of `highestAvailable` is the registry editor that can run as all users but for admin users, it needs full access as that user.

Comment: This means you *cannot* run this program as limited when you're an administrator, doesn't it?

Comment: @Medinoc That is correct. An example of a program configured this way is regedit.