# Why no security prompt when I run my .exe?

Tags: windows, security

I'm developing a document management solution that generates self-extracting .exe's with 7zip, then signs them with signtool... Looking at the generated .exe, I can inspect the signature by looking at the signatures tab of the properties dialog, but I want the "Are you sure you want to run..." prompt, with the signature details presented in the Publisher field. Why is windows letting me run this .exe without confirmation? What do I have to do to see "Are you sure you want to run"?

Comment: I'm not certain which of the two prompts you're talking about, but one of them normally only appears if the file has been downloaded from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it does not require administrator privileges. Add a   [`.exe.manifest` (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) file that has  `requireAdministrator` set.

See also [difference between `highestAvailable` and `requireAdministrator`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12651124/480982)

Comment: In terms of my self-extracting exe, it seems to depend on the module I use. If I Use 7zCon.sfx, no prompt. If I use 7z.sfx, I get the prompt.